# Serialization settings for MongoDB

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, serialization

Is there any way to serialize only private fields of my object which has **DataMember** attributes in MongoDB?

```
string json = 
    item.ToJson(
        new MongoDB.Bson.IO.JsonWriterSettings() 
        { 
            GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard, 
            Indent = false, 
            OutputMode = MongoDB.Bson.IO.JsonOutputMode.JavaScript 
        }
     );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a public field from being serialized use the [BsonIgnore](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.0/html/0b6cf485-682b-cbdf-25b4-b28401824c78.htm) attribute:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Brand;

    public string Model;

    [BsonIgnore]
    public double Price;
}
```

In the sample code above the price field will be ignored when the class is serialized.